# Need an practical method to model this bike wheel

Tags: modeling

I have been struggling all day today to get this modeled right and failed. Would anyone give me some tips? The result I have is beyond bad. Can not even get the rim done.

Thanks a lot~ This is driving me crazy. :D

[image]

Please do not laugh at me. This is what I have done (the fifth version. lol). Its passed midnight, can not sleep by thinking about it. lol

[image]

Comment: Hi. Which part is the issue?

Comment: The Rim so far. lol I have not gotten any further than that.

Comment: Don't forget that in real life, the parts are not joint.

Comment: I tried this way, it also worked. A little more work than the answer LEMON provided. Thanks again. And I am really happy with the outcome. Journey continues! lol The same method, I made the disk break. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ9Aw.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ9Aw.jpg)
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3oqV.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3oqV.jpg)
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HCiI.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HCiI.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principle can be around this:

We are in top view here, there is a mirror modifier along Z and a subdivision surface:

[image]

From left to right:

Add a circle with 6 edges. Shift it a bit along Z (for the mirror and rim thickness).

Extrude all and scale down <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

Rotate the center part.

Select all the faces and inset <kbd>I</kbd>.

Extrude along Z <kbd>E</kbd> to the mirror center.

Delete the faces <kbd>X</kbd>, faces only.

This is only an approach. Of course you need to work a bit more to make it accurate to the picture.

[image]

Comment: Was about to delete this answer seeing your current result... But anyway, if that can help...

Comment: Lemon, thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Really really appreciate it. Your answer helps A LOT! I am going to work on it right away to figure it out.